# "Permission denied" for access to file in AVD Downloads directory

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

I tried in vain attempting to use a file that I put into the default Downloads folder in my Android Studio AVD device.

My app needs to use the setup file in the Downloads folder when run for the first time, and to have the tool properly customized.

I know I have to add permissions at the Manifest, and I did.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And I tested all the src & des file or dir with `File.exists()` and things are there. But I just can't copy the file in Downloads to my app storage (`getFilesDir()`) or unzip into it..

I get the Downloads path with

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

But seems the path is still on the internal NVM. There is emulated external SDCARD in the AVD, but no folders in there yet. I'm starting to wonder whether the Downloads folder is still treated as internal by the AVD, so the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` permission for 'external storage' has no effect for it??

If so.. what can I do to fix this? Or is this an AVD bug?

PS 
The path for the Downloads dir shows:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Download/
```

Some updates since this was posted last month:

Here is what I know so far.

API version seems to make the difference. The above issue was running Oreo (API 26). I just tried it on KitKat (API 19), and the file was found at

```
/storage/sdcard/Download/
```

Oreo was looking at

```
/storage/emulated/0/Download/
```

and it kept returning "Permission denied". But KitKat don't seem to have issue with opening the file at the Downloads dir.

But I'm still really puzzled with this. Anybody has more insight?

Answer (score 0):

New Android now need to obtain the user permission at runtime.

The following codes should credit to Konstantin H. who has been generous to share & teach his knowledge.

```
// Credit: Konstantin H.
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
         if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
    // Explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
        }
          requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an
    // app-defined int constant that should be quite unique

        return;
   } // Konstantin H.
```

and of course for write permission:

```
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
    // Explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
    }
    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    return;
}
```